# how can i write this query in node js sequelize

Tags: node.js, codeigniter, npm, sequelize.js

This is Codeigniter code. I try to this query in nodejs

```
$this->db->where('feature', $feature);
$this->db->where(1);
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($payment12); $i++) {
    $this->db->or_where("FIND_IN_SET('" . $payment12[$i] . "', payment)");
}
$this->db->where(1);
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($coin); $i++) {
    $this->db->or_where("FIND_IN_SET('" . $coin[$i] . "', coin_id)");
}
$this->db->like('name', $website_name);
$this->db->where(1);
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($location); $i++) {
    $this->db->or_where("FIND_IN_SET('" . $location[$i] . "', location)");
}
```

Here sample MySql Query

```
 SELECT *, (fees + privacy + speed + limits + trusted + easy_use) AS totalRank FROM `Websites` WHERE ( `feature` = '2' ) AND ( 1 IS NULL OR FIND_IN_SET('credit', payment) OR FIND_IN_SET('bank', payment) ) AND ( 1 IS NULL OR FIND_IN_SET('ZEC', coin_id) OR FIND_IN_SET('BTC', coin_id) ) AND ( `name` LIKE '%coin%' ESCAPE '!' ) AND ( 1 IS NULL OR FIND_IN_SET('USA', location) OR FIND_IN_SET('IND', location) ) AND `status` = 1 ORDER BY `totalRank` DESC
```

it's possible to convert in Node.js Sequelize?

Comment: can you please share mysql query for this ?

Comment: you can make raw query in sequelize if you want i can make it for you ?

Comment: Yes, please. You can

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do like this .

```
sequelize.query(" SELECT *, (fees + privacy + speed + limits + trusted + easy_use) AS totalRank FROM `Websites` WHERE ( `feature` = '2' ) AND ( 1 IS NULL OR FIND_IN_SET('credit', payment) OR FIND_IN_SET('bank', payment) ) AND ( 1 IS NULL OR FIND_IN_SET('ZEC', coin_id) OR FIND_IN_SET('BTC', coin_id) ) AND ( `name` LIKE '%coin%' ESCAPE '!' ) AND ( 1 IS NULL OR FIND_IN_SET('USA', location) OR FIND_IN_SET('IND', location) ) AND `status` = 1 ORDER BY `totalRank` DESC", {
    type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT,
    model: Websites
}).then(value => {
    console.log(value);
})
```

Comment: it's not possible in 

`db.websites.findAll({  where: {wid: w_id},}).then(web_list => {
            return resolve({status: 1, msg: "Data Load successfully.", data: web_list});
        })`

Comment: yes , but `FIND_IN_SET ` is not working in sequeliuze mode  for that we have to use raw query even sequelize docs has remove page for `FIND_IN_SET` in sequelize mode .

Comment: i have face same issue  and after much research i have to go with raw query .

Comment: @Vipul24Task if this does ans to your que than please consider this ans as marked !!

Comment: Thank To You @Vyas Arpit, But it's a static query and in dynamic I have thousands of coins and all, how is possible `FIND_IN_SET` every time. your query is perfect. but here I use 2 coins only

Comment: @Vipul24Task Happy to have helped !! Bro :)

Comment: me to, I concrete data like              'if (coins) {
        coins.forEach(c => {
            coin_condi += "OR FIND_IN_SET('" + c + "', coin_id) ";
        })
    }'                   HAHA, is it oK ???????????

Comment: yeah . it'll lightweight query if this does work properly.